# Teardown action in Robot Framework

Tags: python, python-2.7, robotframework

I have a 3 test cases in robot framework and I need to run Teardown actions only Once at last after execution 3 test cases.
How to handle?

```
*** Settings ***
Test Teardown     Teardown Actions
Library           abc.py

*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***
testcase1
    Run Keyword    func1

testcase2
    Run Keyword    func2

testcase3
    Run Keyword    func3


*** Keywords ***
Teardown Actions
    Run Keyword    clear
```

Comment: did you install any library for tear down or it is automatic ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is "Suite Teardown" in robotframework which will run after the execution of all test cases.

[Check this link for more info.](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#suite-setup-and-teardown)

Can be use like this.

```
*** Settings ***
Library         SSHLibrary
Library         OperatingSystem
Library         String
Suite Teardown  Teardown Actions

*** Keywords ***
    Teardown Actions    
        Run Keyword clear

*** Testcases ***
    testcase1 
        Run Keyword func1

    testcase2 
        Run Keyword func2

    testcase3 
        Run Keyword func3
```

Please let me know if more info is required.

Comment: is it mandatory to add a pip install for teardown or it's not like library ? @Dinesh

Comment: @Emna - No. If you have installed Robot Framework, it comes default with it. Check this link - http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html

Comment: It is keyword which comes by default with Robot

Comment: Thanks,  this is my question i asked i'm beginner in robot framework https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44310079/how-to-handle-try-catch-exception-in-ride-robot-framework

Answer (score 0):

In your code, Just replace "Test Teardown" with "Suite Teardown". That's it!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [answer].

Answer (score -2):

Robot Framework have the Suite Teardown which will run once all the test cases of the particular suite are executed.

You can write like this in your scripts:

```
         *** Settings ***
            Library           Selenium2Library
            Library           abc.py
            Suite Teardown    Teardown Actions

        *** Variables ***

        *** Test Cases ***
                testcase1
                Run Keyword    func1

                testcase2
                Run Keyword    func2

                testcase3
                Run Keyword    func3


          *** Keywords ***
               Teardown Actions
               Run Keyword    clear
```

Comment: Indentations for test case and keyword section is not right. Will result in confusion for a newbie. Request author to remove this.