# How to handle try catch exception in ride robot framework?

Tags: user-interface, automated-tests, robotframework, ui-automation, sikuli

I'm using RIDE robotframework, i want to handle an exception when the application is crashed i close it then open a new instance of it.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SikuliLibrary

*** Variables ***
${openProject}    sikuli_captured\\Emna\\openProject.png
${DataBaseSTProject}    sikuli_captured\\Emna\\DataBaseSTProject.png
${testSession}    sikuli_captured\\Emna\\testSession.png
${menu}           sikuli_captured\\menu.png
${fileName}       sikuli_captured\\Emna\\fileName.png
${save}           sikuli_captured\\Emna\\save.png

*** Test Cases ***
createNewProject
    Click    ${menu}
    Click    ${testSession}
    Input Text    ${fileName}    FirstProjecT3
    Click    ${save}

openTestProject
    Click    ${openProject}
    Double Click    ${DataBaseSTProject}
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks for your help :)

[image]

Comment: Do you start the application from Robot Framework, or is it already started? If started using the OperatingSystem library, then you should be able to close the application as well. If that is not the approach, then use the library to kick off a command line script that kills it for you.

Comment: I 'm testing a desktop application using robot framework and RIDE

Comment: Sadly this reaction does not answer the question I asked. Do you start the application using the Robot Framework [Process Library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html) or is it started as part of your test script? How would you functionally determine that an application has crashed? A number of seconds that an image is not detected? Do you start each test case with a new instance of your application under test?

Comment: I 'm new with robotframework i started last week to test an application by writing scripts with robotframework using `RIDE`. The problem is that in some cases our application get crashed if a problem of memory or others ... (those problem of crash exists but not always and we did'nt find the full scenario of crash to fix it by developer of the application) because we have automated scripts there when we launch all test cases together there is a small probability that the application crashes while testing (a message that app is not responding)

Comment: i want to create a test and insert it in every script so that if a crash appears the application is closed and reopened and the last test is done another time. Do you get my point ?

Comment: The message: "App is not responding" you mentioned ([Google Images](https://www.google.nl/search?q=windows+application+is+not+responding&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X)), is that the way you determine that the application has crashed?

Comment: Exactly, this is the message of crash that i told you, if it happens i click into close the program and reopen the app again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Robot Framework the concept of *Try/Catch/Finally* is not present. In essence your `Test Case body` is the *Try* part of this trifecta and the other two are combined into the `[Teardown]` keywords of the respective [Test Suite](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#suite-setup-and-teardown), [Test Case](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#suite-setup-and-teardown) or [Keyword](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#user-keyword-teardown) sections.

Within this Teardown keyword it is possible to recognize if a Test Case has Passed or Failed through the [automatic variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#automatic-variables) of Robot Framework itself or the `Run Keyword If ...` [family of keywords](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If). This would allow you to create a separate section for the Catch, and finally. In the below section of code an example is given of a pass and fail test case, each using the same Teardown.

This construct should allow you to check if a step in a test case failed, verify if the application has crashed (through the Sikuli image test of the popup) and then close and restart the application.

```
*** Test Cases ***

Open Application and fail
    Log to Console    About to Fail
    Fail
    Log to Console    Will never trigger.
    [Teardown]    Generic Test Case Teardown

Open Application and Pass
    Log to Console    About to Pass
    No Operation
    Log to Console    Will trigger.
    [Teardown]    Generic Test Case Teardown

*** Keywords ***
Generic Test Case Teardown
    # Catch of Try Catch Finally
    Run Keyword If Test Failed    Test Case Catch

    # Finally of Try Catch Finally
    #  RKITS is only executed when test passed.
    Run Keyword If Test Passed    Test Case Finally
    #  Always executed regardless of test execution status.
    Log To Console     I am always executed.

Test Case Catch
    Log To Console    Test Case Catch

Test Case Finally
    Log To Console    Test Case Finally
```

Answer (score 3):

Since robot framework 5.0 it should be possible to use try/catch now.[Release notes](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/doc/releasenotes/rf-5.0b1.rst#try-except)
Here is an example from the documentation:

```
*** Test Cases ***
First example
    TRY
        Some Keyword
    EXCEPT    Error message
        Error Handler Keyword
    END
    Keyword Outside
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to Kootstra's answer, you might want to test if a function fails without the test actually failing.

```
*** Keywords ***
Do Something And Fail
    Log To Console  FAIL
    Fail

Do Something And Succeed
    Log To Console  SUCCESS

Test Something
    ${success}=  Run Keyword And Return Status  Do Something And Fail
    Log To Console  ${success}  #False
    ${success}=  Run Keyword And Return Status  Do Something And Succeed
    Log To Console  ${success}  #True
```

See [Run Keyword And Return Status](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Return%20Status) documentation.
Combine this with `Run Keyword If` to create behavior that depends on whether a keyword succeeds.